# deploying app on openshift - git and ssh key not working

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

I'd like to deploy an app on OpenShift. I followed this tutorial:

https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-getting-started.html#step1

Works fine until I want to push it. Then I get the following:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xxxx.rhcloud.com,54.88.2.59' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I read in another post that I should copy the private keys from my user/.ssh folder (I'm on Windows 7) into git' ssh folder.

But in my git folder, there is no ssh folder, just a certs folder

What do I need to do exactly?

**EDIT**

I ran rhc setup and got this error:

```
Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself.  Please
run 'chmod 600 C:\Users\xxx\.ssh\id_rsa'

An SSH connection could not be established to jenkins-xxx.rhcloud.com.
Your SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be
responding. Could not parse PKey: no start line (ArgumentError)
```

Which ssh configuration? On my computer? On OpenShift?

Comment: On your computer. Try the `chmod 600`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to run `rhc setup` which will guide you through the process of setting up an ssh key (will generate one for you, if you'd like). Details can be found in [Remote connection (SSH)](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html).

You can also use the OpenShift web interface to upload your ssh key, if you already have one that you plan to use.

Comment: @user3813234, if you don't mind, you can delete your id_rsa and re-run the rhc setup, have a new key pair generated & uploaded.

Comment: I did that. I erased id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, reran rhc setup and did chmod 600 on id_isa... the same access right error when I do git push.  rhc ssh access works, by the way. Maybe I'm doing somethig wrong with git? But I'm just following their tutorial...

Comment: And when I look in the open shift web console, my public key is listed

Comment: I thought that it's caused by a corrupted key, which does not seem to be the case. I'm sorry, I'm unable to verify this with Git for Windows, but it could really be caused by the (Windows) Git Bash not having access to your key. This may help (http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key). If not, hopefully someone else using Git Bash in Windows may share their experience here.

Answer (score 1):

A "Permission denied" error means that the server rejected your connection. You need the ssh key, because you don't have access rights.

You need to generate SSH key.